# How to make editable menu in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, treeview

I want to create a aspx page which will have menu structure in it.

```
Ex:fruit
   apple
   orange
  color
   red
   blue
```

I want on edit button click i will be able to edit the content of menu and also add new root menu and sub menu.
How can i achieve it?which control will help me the best?

Comment: i dont understand ur question really ? u want to use a dinamic menu in page ?

Comment: yes i want to edit and add new menu items dynamically.@Mennan

Answer (score 0):

You Can use radtree view in AJAX Controls, this will help you... and for editing and adding use usercontrols